# Issue with Reading Frames from CCTV Camera Using OpenCV via RTSP

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

```
import sys
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np


class CameraManager:
    def __init__(self, camera_uris):
        self.camera_uris = camera_uris
        self.cameras = self._initialize_cameras()

    def _initialize_cameras(self):
        cameras = []
        for uri in self.camera_uris:
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(uri)
            if not cap.isOpened():
                print("Cannot open camera")
                sys.exit()
            cameras.append(cap)
        return cameras

    def read_frames(self,skip_frames=3):
        frames = []
        for index, cam in enumerate(self.cameras):
            for _ in range(skip_frames):
                cam.read()
            ret, frame = cam.read()
            # print(int(cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)))
            if not ret:
                print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
                self.cameras[index] = cv2.VideoCapture(self.camera_uris[index])
                frame = np.zeros((1080, 1920, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
            frames.append(frame)
        return frames

def resize_images(images, new_width=640, new_height=480):
    """
    Resize all images in the list to the specified dimensions.
    """
    resized_images = []
    for img in images:
        resized = cv2.resize(img, (new_width, new_height))
        resized_images.append(resized)
    return resized_images

def calculate_grid_size(num_images):
    """
    Calculate the grid size based on the number of images.
    """
    if num_images == 0:
        return 0, 0
    rows = ((num_images - 1) // 3) + 1
    cols = 3
    return rows, cols

def merge_images_in_grid(images):
    """
    Merge images into a grid layout, with the grid size dynamically calculated.
    """
    if not images:
        raise ValueError("No images to merge")

    # Resize images
    images = resize_images(images, 640, 480)

    # Calculate grid size
    grid_rows, grid_cols = calculate_grid_size(len(images))

    # Get dimensions of the resized images
    img_height, img_width, _ = images[0].shape

    # Grid dimensions
    grid_width = img_width * grid_cols
    grid_height = img_height * grid_rows

    # Create an empty black image for the grid
    merged_image = np.zeros((grid_height, grid_width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    # Place each image in the grid
    for i, img in enumerate(images):
        row = i // grid_cols
        col = i % grid_cols
        merged_image[row * img_height:(row + 1) * img_height, col * img_width:(col + 1) * img_width, :] = img

    return merged_image

class MainApplication:
    def __init__(self):
        self.camera_uris = ["rtsp://admin:srivas123@192.168.1.23","rtsp://admin:srivas123@192.168.1.22","rtsp://admin:srivas123@192.168.1.21","rtsp://admin:srivas123@192.168.1.20"]
        self.camera_manager = CameraManager(camera_uris=self.camera_uris)

    def run(self):
        frame_number = 0
        while True:
            frames = self.camera_manager.read_frames()
            time.sleep(0.5)
            merge_image = merge_images_in_grid(images=frames)
            cv2.namedWindow('output', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
            cv2.imshow('output', merge_image)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        app = MainApplication()
        app.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Exiting ..")
```

In this code, I manage multiple CCTV cameras connected via RTSP (Real-Time Streaming Protocol). The program continuously captures frames from these cameras, selectively skipping a set number of frames. After reading a frame, it's added to a list which is then returned. Instead of implementing YOLO object detection, I've introduced a sleep interval of 0.5 seconds. Following this pause, the captured frames are displayed using OpenCV's imshow function

The program runs without any errors when time.sleep(0.5) is not included, but including this line causes an error.Below the error messages

```
Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...
[h264 @ 0x1c6bbc0] error while decoding MB 114 18, bytestream -35
Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...
Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...
[hevc @ 0x13d3840] Could not find ref with POC 6
[h264 @ 0x1c2e9c0] error while decoding MB 102 13, bytestream -5
[h264 @ 0x244bfc0] error while decoding MB 12 31, bytestream -7
Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...
Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...
[hevc @ 0x1c42900] Could not find ref with POC 0
[rtsp @ 0x1ade880] RTP: PT=60: bad cseq 1d84 expected=0ba8
[hevc @ 0x1c27880] Could not find ref with POC 36
```

When I replace the time.sleep(0.5) with YOLO object detection, the program also encounters an error.

why the program throws an error when time.sleep(0.5) is included or when YOLO object detection is implemented. Identifying the root cause of these errors will help in finding an appropriate solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  including ```time.sleep(0.5)``` causes an error.  What is the error?  What is the other error when you replace it with a YOLO object detection?

Comment: Same type of error got when i replace with yolo detection also

Comment: @RajeshKumarS can you pleas edit your post to include the traceback? i.e. what is the error message...

Comment: @TinoD I already include error message. Below i add it again
```[hevc @ 0x1c42900] Could not find ref with POC 0
[rtsp @ 0x1ade880] RTP: PT=60: bad cseq 1d84 expected=0ba8
[hevc @ 0x1c27880] Could not find ref with POC 36```

Comment: Quick guess: the `sleep` might be needed because otherwise you are requesting new frames from the cameras before they have any new ones available. In other words, your loop might run faster than the framerate of your cameras.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, @thom747. I have a question regarding your feedback. In the past, when I didn't use sleep or YOLO detection, I didn't encounter any errors because sleep introduced a delay in fetching new frames. However, now I am facing these types of errors.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: My question is simple why I encounter this error hevc @ 0x13d3840] Could not find ref with POC 6
[h264 @ 0x1c2e9c0] error while decoding MB 102 13, bytestream -5
[h264 @ 0x244bfc0] error while decoding